# Standard Java pattern for wrapping a timeout around an errant process

Tags: java, concurrency

I'm using a 3rd party function (say runThird()) that has a tendency to loop indefinitely and has no timeout facility built in. However, I can kill it (killThird()). Is there a proper way to do this (i.e. some concurrency construct)?

Here's my attempt at this:

```
java.lang.Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(TIMEOUT);
        } catch (java.lang.InterruptedException e){
            return;
        }
        killThird();
    }
});                                
thread.start();

RunThirdResult rtr = runThird();

if (thread != null){
    thread.interrupt();
}
```

But I'm not sure I like the overhead of creating a thread, using sleep and the contrivance of interrupting the thread if runThird() returns.

Comment: You can work with ExecutorService, Future and Callable (Runnable would be enough if there is no return value). You would submit a Callable (which runs your `third()`) to the Executor and on the returned Future, you'll block with timeout.

Comment: Note that you can use `TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(xx)`, it is easier to the eyes than a plain `Thread.sleep(xx)` ;)

Comment: Does your third party method run a result?

Comment: @fge, yes the 3rd party does return a result. I'll amend the question.

Answer (score 3):

Let's assume `runThird()` retuns Integer ...

```
// ...  in your class ...
private ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();


//... then somewhere, where you want to call runThird()
Future<Integer> handle = executor.submit( new Callable<Integer>(){
    @Override Integer call(){
         return runThird(); // Assume you made it available here ...
    }
}

Integer result;
try{
   result = handle.get(TIMEOUT,UNIT); // TIMEOUT and UNIT declared somewhere above ...
}
catch(TimeoutException ex) {
   killThird();
   // HANDLE result not being set!
}

// ... use result.
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use a ScheduledExecutorService for this.  Schedule it to be killed.

```
volatile RunThirdResult rtr;

ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

service.schedule(new Runnable(){
   public void run(){
      if(rtr == null) killThird();
   }
}, TIMEOUT_IN_MILLIS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

RunThirdResult rtr = runThird();
```

Comment: +1 even shorter than my suggestion and not using an Exception. Nice.

Comment: ...but depending on the Implementation of runThird/killThird, there could be sideeffects, right? What happens if I call it twice in a row? The scheduled kill of the first could kill a second call. Well, depending on an implementation I don't know. But it could.

Comment: @Fildor yes, you're right.  Both our implementations suffer the same fate.  Unless the OP offers more information there is not much else that can be assumed in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that? The most interesting part is `StoppableWrapper#stop()`, cause graceful cancellation is a hard thing and there's no common approach for all cases. One time you need to clear filesystem, other time to close network connection, etc. In your sample, you just call `interrupt()`, so I assumed `runThird()` honors being interrupted and will take care to clean things behind itself.

```
class Sample {
    final ExecutorService tasksExecutor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

    class StoppableWrapper implements Runnable {
        private final Runnable task;
        private final CountDownLatch executed;

        StoppableWrapper(Runnable task, CountDownLatch executed) {
            this.task = task;
            this.executed = executed;
        }

        void stop() {
            // e.g. Thread.currentThread().interrupt()
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            task.run();
            executed.countDown();
        }
    }

    public void scheduleTimingOutTaskExecution(final long timeout) {
        final CountDownLatch executed = new CountDownLatch(1);

        final StoppableWrapper command = new StoppableWrapper(new RunThirdInstance(), executed);
        tasksExecutor.execute(command);
        tasksExecutor.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    if (!executed.await(timeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {
                        command.stop();
                        // additionally, you can make stop() return boolean after time-out as well and handle failure 
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // handle stopper exception here
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: That complicated? I'd submit a `new Callable(){ public V call(){ return runThird();} }` Then `get(TIMEOUT,UNITS)` on the resulting Future and in the `catch(TimeoutException)` I'd `killThird()`. (With "V" substituted correctly, of course).

Comment: Yes, fine, but code above gives more flexibility when stopping task -- you have `stop()` method you can override with proper shutdown logic. Maybe, OP doesn't need it in this particular case, but I thought this way when writing an example.